# replace ILogger<T> in servicecollection for integration tests

Tags: c#, integration-testing

I have some integration tests and for logging we used

```
serviceCollection.AddLogging()
```

now we need to test that some info is logged in the dependency services where the injected services are ILogger

All the examples I found are for Mock<ILogger>.Object injected directly in the constructor. But that does not apply to me since the logger is for a dependency service and not the constructed one.

Is there an example on how to replace ILogger or ILoggerFactory for unit testing in ServiceCollection.

Edit: how the unit tests look like

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection().AddLogging();
....
serviceCollection.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IDependecyService>, IDependecyService, _ => mockService.Object);
....
var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
var sut = new Sut(serviceProvider.GetService<IService>(), ....);
```

The sut does not have any logging injected

IService needs to be injected the IDependecyService

IDependecyService need to be injected the ILogger
and this logger I need to mock.

Like I already said the serviceCollection has the ILogger<> and IFactoryLogger but I do not know how to replace them in order to give my mock of ILogger

This is just an example but there are other services with their own ILogger but I need to mock for now only the ILogger the other ILogger<> should remain as AddLogging has done it.

Comment: Could you give us a sample that `class` you want to mock?

Comment: `AddLogging` doesn't configure logging, it registers your already configured logging as a service.  You don't need to replace `ILogger` at all, you need to provide a test logger in your logging configuration.  That's what those `Mock<ILogger>.Object` methods do. There are better options though. You can add a text logger that writes to a different location. You can create an XUnit logger that writes to XUnit's output. Or a class that stores events in a queue or list for inspection

Comment: What does your *test* code look like? That's where you need to register your own logger. Either in `ConfigureLogging` if you use Startup, or through `builder.Logging` if you use Minimal APIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this using the ILoggerProvider.

I mocked this and returned only for the needed category the mocked ILogger

```
var mockLoggerProvider = new Mock<ILoggerProvider>();
mockLoggerProvider.Setup(p => p.CreateLogger(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns<string>(c =>
{
    if(c == typeof(...).FullName)
    {
        return ...;// mocked logger
    }
    return NullLoggerProvider.Instance.CreateLogger(c);
});
new ServiceCollection().AddLogging(l => l.ClearProviders().AddProvider(mockLoggerProvider.Object))
```